# Laravel 5 - Helper on Blade not working

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I have this error when I used `{{ Helper::test(); }}` on a blade

[image]

and on my `config/app.php`, I already have 
[image]

and this is inside of my `Helper.php`

```
<?php namespace App;

class Helper {
    public static function test() {
        return "wa";
    }
}
```

and I already done the `composer.json` then run the `composer dump-autoload`

```
...
"autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        },
        "files": [
            "app/Helper.php"
        ]
    },
...
```

I don't know what I missed, is there any suggestion to be able to use the helper on a blade on a laravel 5?

Comment: Remove `bootstrap/cache/services.json` file and test again. This file will be generated automatically

Comment: @manix don't have that file

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in two different ways,

**First**

Remove,

```
 "files": [
            "app/Helper.php"
        ]
```

from `composer.json` and remove

```
"Helper" =>"App\Helper"
```

from `app.php` and than use like below,

```
{{ App\Helper::test() }}
```

**Second**

keep `composer.json` as it is and remove

```
namespace App;
```

from `Helper.php` than run `composer dump-autoload`
and use it as below,

```
{{ Helper::test() }}
```

Comment: `App\Helper::test();` is not necessary if you use facedes. `Helper::test()` should be enough.

Comment: @manix Facades provide a "static" interface to classes that are available in the application's service container. Helper.php is not in service container. [this](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/facades#creating-facades) is how you create a facade

Comment: I've removed the `namespace App;` and it's working on the blade, while when I used it on the controller I've got this error `Cannot redeclare class Helper`

Comment: @StormSpirit can you please update your question with `controller` code?